# How to generate pdf with fixed page size and fixed content size using itextpdf5

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to create pdf with fixed size content e.g 4/3 inches content size if pdf page size is 4/3 inches, Content size should remain same if i increase the pdf page size.

I have following code to generate pdf.

Can i achieve it? If yes then how??

Note :  Current size doesn't fit to page its smaller than page size.

```
public class PrintResource {

    private static final String PDF_FILENAME = "barcodeFile.pdf";    

    private void createConatainerPDF(String containerId) throws IOException, DocumentException {
        Document document = new Document();
        Rectangle documentSize = new Rectangle(288,216); // 4/3 inche
        document.setPageSize(documentSize); 
        document.setMargins(7,0,0,0);        
        OutputStream outputStream = null;        
        try {
            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("F://Mukesh/"+PDF_FILENAME));
            PdfWriter.getInstance(document, outputStream);
            document.open();
            document.add(new Paragraph("Behaelter"));
            document.add(new Paragraph(containerId));
            Image awtImage = generatetBarcodeImage(containerId);
            //awtImage.getScaledInstance(500, 500,1);
            com.itextpdf.text.Image img = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(awtImage, null);

            document.add(img);
        } finally {
            document.close();
            outputStream.close();
        }
    }

    private Image generatetBarcodeImage(String barcodeNumber) {
        Barcode128 barcode128 = new Barcode128();
        barcode128.setCode(barcodeNumber);
        barcode128.setCodeType(Barcode.CODE128);        
        barcode128.setSize(100);
        barcode128.setBarHeight(50);
        barcode128.setN(3);
        barcode128.setX(2f);

        //barcode128.setBar(100);
        return barcode128.createAwtImage(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);
    }

    private void deletePDFFile() {
        new File(PDF_FILENAME).delete();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new PrintResource().createConatainerPDF("B-0000001");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DocumentException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What is the problem?

Comment: Currently it generate small content rather fit to 4/3 inch page. I have given page size like  = Rectangle documentSize = new Rectangle(288,216); but the actual print come too small. I mean content is too small not fit the page

Comment: Why don't you say so in your question. I was already thinking of an answer that was totally irrelevant because you didn't mention that the content was too small. I thought it was too big.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes thanks for suggestion it was my mistake. Edited question